# CDK Virtual scroll on nested list with two ngFor loops in Angular

Tags: angular, angular-material

I have a nested list with two ngFor loops in my Angular app, and I want to implement virtual scroll so that only the parent element has a scrollbar. How can I implement virtual scroll on this nested list and ensure that the scrollbar is applied only to the parent element?

```
<mat-autocomplete>
    <ng-container *ngFor="let item of OuterArray">
      <mat-optgroup>
         <span class="d-flex-items-center">
            <mat-icon>group</mat-icon>
            <span>Team</span>
        </span>
       <ng-container *ngFor="let user of item.innerArray">
         <span>User</span>
       </ng-container>
      <mat-optgroup>
    </ng-container>
 </mat-autocomplete>
```

And what are other ways to make this list more performant in case of large dataset.